# open another app by packagename in testunit Android

Tags: android

When I try to open app in android by test unit, it has some problem. Some phones can do it, some not. Why?

```
@Test
public void startApp() {
    String pkgName = "com.tencent.wework";
    Context deviceContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = deviceContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    deviceContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```